# Compact framework see who uses a file

Tags: compact-framework

Is there a way in CF to see which process uses a certain file?

I have an SDF which I want to delete and then overwrite it with another sdf. File.Delete throws an IOException saying file is in use.

I am sure I have closed all DB connections.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to find which process locks a file on WinCE or Windows Mobile.

You should double check if all open connections and references to the sdf files are closed from your code.

As a workaround write another 'updater' app. Then close your main app and start the updater app to replace the sdf file. The updater then could start the main app after the update. You may use named events to sync this: Start new process and wait for 'process started' named event. Then close main app. After update start main app and wait for a named event which states that main app has started, then close updater app.